# Select a number between 1 to 1000 in sequence php

Tags: php

I have stored 1000 images in a folder named as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on. I want to show these images in a sequence. Whenever page load it must show the next image. Even if visitor is same or changed it must show the next image. For example

First hit: 1.jpg is shown.

Second hit: 2.jpg is shown.

Third hit: 3.jpg is shown.

and so on.

How can I generate a number between 1 to 1000 in a sequence?

Comment: You should at least try writing the code first and then posting what you're having trouble with here.

But if you're going to need to use shared memory if you want to track a variable across all users. You could also just read and write to some other file and grab it from there.

Comment: Previously, I am doing the same thing. I was storing the number in a text file and then increment it in every next hit. But problem arises when when 10 or more concurrent use hit the page. I can share this code but it really not solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this..

1. you can use temporary table to store "recently which number of image has been showed?"
2. session or cookie to store recent number.

in the php code:

1. find recent number (for example 3)
2. increment that recent number and  (3+1=4)
3. show that 4.jpg

temporary table would be a best option as i guess.

Comment: This is a good answer, but to clarify: sessions and cookies are *customer specific*, so if you want customer A to visit and see 1.jpg, customer B to visit and see 2.jpg, then a table is probably your best bet.

Comment: Cookies aren't relevant here since that is on a user by user basis.

Comment: Thanks. Both Bing and Difster are right. Cookies cannot be used for this purpose. Let me give a try to temporary tables.

Comment: Yes! you are right. it depends on the features. Table is obviously the best option.

Answer (score 1):

[Farsay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385195/7198013) option number one would be the way to go about this. I would like to add further clarification on that. You will precisely have to follow these step.

1. Create a table to store the views on the images.
2. On each visit hit the table and find the last row inserted.
3. Check if we are at the last item ( Using a variable that has this number ) and show the first one.
4. If not show the next one.
5. Add an entry to the table.